# Prepackage Arch Linux (ARM) with packages before installing

Tags: arch-linux, sd-card

How can I make an Arch Linux ISO to load into a usb, that would contain all of my favourite packages and configuration, preloaded?

I want to do it with an Arch Linux ISO, then with Arch Linux ARM, I guess the process would be pretty much the same.

EDIT:

I just read about [ArchISO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/archiso), but it doesnt seem to care about what comes *AFTER* the livecd part.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is actually on the ArchISO page you linked:

Installing packages
"You will want to create a list of packages you want installed on your live CD system. A file full of package names, one-per-line, is the format for this. This is great for special interest live CDs, just specify packages you want in packages.both and bake the image."

Comment: But that would simply install them on the livecd, it doesn't say that it would also install it to the system installed by the livecd.

Answer (score 0):

Using `archiso` you may place packages and scripts into your iso, to do whatever you specifically want in your live image. You just need to

- modify `packages.both`
- place scripts you want in your iso into `airootfs/root`

Using this a colleague and me created our own custom installer, see https://github.com/Trick-17/arch-installer (derived from [this guide](https://blog.chendry.org/2015/02/06/automating-arch-linux-installation.html)).
Maybe something like this is what you mean with "*AFTER* the livecd part"?

Note that we did not do this, but you may also have scripts run automatically on booting into the live image, you just need to place them in the right folder.